# Keep sticky posts out of query unless they have featured image

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, sticky-post

I have a query running which prevents posts without various criteria from appearing, one of these is the necessity to have a featured image. Sticky posts however seem to end up in the query regardless. How can I achieve this?

```
    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $articles_no,
            'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'post__not_in' => $a_empty_titles,
            // remove post formats as per theme options ( using $hide from above )
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                        'terms' => $hide
                    )
                )
            );
        $fp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <?php 
                $thumbnail_span = "span4";
                if( $fp_query->have_posts() ) : while( $fp_query->have_posts() ) : $fp_query->the_post(); ?>

                ... Typical Formatting Follows ...
                ... Posts without featured images should have been excluded but "sticky" posts seem to persist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Codex article on [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> ignore_sticky_posts (boolean) - ignore sticky posts or not. Default value is 0 - don't ignore sticky posts. Note: ignore/exclude sticky posts being included at the beginning of posts returned, but the sticky post will still be returned in the natural order of that list of posts returned.

Adding `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` to your `$args` array will stop sticky posts from showing up when you don't want them. Then `'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',` can succeed at filtering out posts without featured images.